# Loop through table and update a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have the following table:

| Id | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some thing |
| 2 | value |

This table contains a lot of rows and what I'm trying to do is to update all the Category values to change every first letter to caps. For example, **some thing** should be **Some Thing**.

At the moment this is what I have:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET Category = (SELECT UPPER(LEFT(Category,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(Category,2,LEN(Category))) FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 1)
WHERE Id = 1;
```

But there are two problems, the first one is trying to change the Category Value to upper, because only works ok for 1 len words (hello=> Hello, hello world => Hello world) and the second one is that I'll need to run this query X times following the Where Id = X logic. So my question is how can I update X rows? I was thinking in a cursor but I don't have too much experience with it.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=095a3a0b5f130538667b5722a85b62a6) to play with.

Comment: Regarding your second question in isolation: There is no need for a subselect when calculating the updated value. Your original statement could be written `UPDATE MyTable SET Category = UPPER(LEFT(Category,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(Category,2,LEN(Category)))` to update all records in one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the words apart, apply the capitalization, then munge the words back together. No, you shouldn't be worrying about subqueries and `Id` because you should always approach *updating a set of rows* as a set-based operation and not one row at a time.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT Id, NewCat = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
    UPPER(LEFT(value,1)),
    SUBSTRING(value,2,57)), ' ') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value, Category))
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT t.Id, t.Category, s.value 
    FROM dbo.MyTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Category, ' ') AS s
  ) AS x GROUP BY Id
)
UPDATE t
  SET t.Category = cte.NewCat
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS t
  INNER JOIN cte ON t.Id = cte.Id;
```

This assumes your category doesn't have *non-consecutive* duplicates within it; for example, `bora frickin bora` would get messed up (meanwhile `bora bora fickin` would be fine). It also assumes a case insensitive collation (which could be catered to if necessary).

In Azure SQL Database you can use the new `enable_ordinal` argument to `STRING_SPLIT()` but, for now, you'll have to rely on hacks like `CHARINDEX()`.

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b4581806150bd2b243fc5e156a45c257) (thank you for the head start!)